# Поиск курса/статьи на тему "Обучение нейронных сетей"

Tags: нейронные-сети

Диплом требует реализации нейронной сети для классификации изображений. В интернете есть несколько примеров реализации таких сетей, но все из них загружают данные MNIST или CSAR-10.

Суть вопроса: есть ли статья или курс в которой рассмотрена и показана реализация обучение нейросети на своих данных? Желательно чтобы информация была доступной для понимания.

Также, если у кого-нибудь есть желание и возможность объяснить реализацию обучения нейросети на своих данных, то я буду очень рад данной возможности и, в свою очередь, обещаю, что надоедать или наглеть не буду.

Спасибо!

Comment: Напишите на afanasyev.workbox@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хоть что-то читали по нейросетям конкретно и по машинному обучению  более глобально, то несомненно уже знаете, что большинство задач распадается на две составляющие (этапа).

Этап 1. На вход алгоритма обучения подается некоторый заранее размеченный, по возможности - как можно бОльший (обучающий) набор данных, на котором и происходит процесс обучения - т.е. построение конкретного классификатора (то-ли в виде функции, то-ли в виде алгоритма, то-ли в виде искусственной нейронной сети)

Этап 2. Используя построенный на первом этапе классификатор решается задача классификации для новых данных, не встречающихся в обучающем наборе.

Таким образом построение нейросети на MNIST или CSAR-10 отличается от построения нейросети на "своих данных" только тем, что это "свои данные" надо иметь. Размеченные и побольше.
Дальше действуете абсолютно аналогично, в точном соответствии с приведенной выше двухэтапной схемой.

Правда - остается вопрос, какой класс классификаторов выбрать. Или какую разновидность нейросети -  если вы уже определились, что именно эту разновидность классификаторов хотите использовать. Но тут уже  действуют на основе знаний, опыта и интуиции, основываясь на понимании того, в каких прикладных областях и для каких типов входных данный какой из классификаторов обычно показывает лучшие результаты (строит более точные модели). Тут уже "общих правил" нет -  только эксперимент и анализ.

Надеюсь, что эта информация "доступна для понимания".

Comment: В дипломе, скорей всего, будет классификация хитмапов. Я не могу найти понятную информацию аля "вот сюда вписываем каталог картинок для обучения, а сюда для проверки" (конечно же, не на таком низком уровне, но все же).

Comment: @Nikvay -  ну вам же уже даже на другом сайте ответили то-же, что я написал выше, только предельно кратко "всё то же самое, что и на готовом датасете, только данные вы сами размечаете". И ничего другого быть не может. Т.е. берете ЛЮБОЙ понравившийся вам источник по реализации сетей и вместо описанных там данных вставляете свои, только предварительно аккуратненько размеченные. И не важно, "для проверки" или "для обучения".

Comment: Если Вы про этот гайд [гайд](https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-for-image-classification-using-keras-c47ccf09c8c8), то у меня выдает ошибки. Наверно, нужно уточнить, что я работаю в гугл колаб. Загружать данные в виртуалку я научился, но вот описывать у меня не получается. Также попробовал вот по [этому гайду](https://www.reg.ru/blog/keras/). Тоже выдает ошибки. Не могу разобраться в причине и пофиксить. Именно из-за этого прошу направить на универсальный код для описания данных.
Простите меня за мою тупость, но я реально не понимаю. Сижу уже не первый вечер, но без прогресса.

Answer (score 0):

Уже numpy.random.sample((10,10)) свой набор обучающий.